# Identify increasing features in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

I have a data frame that present some features with cumulative values. I need to identify those features in order to revert the cumulative values. 
This is how my dataset looks (plus about 50 variables):

```
a      b     
346    17    
76     52    
459    70    
680    96    
679    167   
246    180
```

What I wish to achieve is:

```
a      b     
346    17    
76     35    
459    18    
680    26    
679    71   
246    13
```

I've seem this answer, but it first revert the values and then try to identify the columns. Can't I do the other way around? First identify the features and then revert the values?

> [Finding cumulative features in dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195045/finding-cumulative-features-in-dataframe)

What I do at the moment is run the following code in order to give me the feature's names with cumulative values:

```
 def accmulate_col(value):
     count = 0
     count_1 = False
     name = []
     for i in range(len(value)-1):
         if value[i+1]-value[i] >= 0:
             count += 1
         if value[i+1]-value[i] > 0:
             count_1 = True
     name.append(1) if count == len(value)-1 and count_1 else name.append(0)
     return name

 df.apply(accmulate_col)
```

Afterwards, I save these features names manually in a list called cum_features and revert the values, creating the desired dataset:

```
df_clean = df.copy()
df_clean[cum_cols] = df_clean[cum_features].apply(lambda col: np.diff(col, prepend=0))
```

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: You should definitely be favouring difference calculating functions over doing the iterations yourself. Having said that, could you provide an example dataframe to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify which columns have increasing* values throughout the whole column, you will need to apply conditions on all the values. So in that sense, you *have* to use the values first to figure out what columns fit the conditions.

With that out of the way, given a dataframe such as:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': [1,2,3,4],
     'b': [4,3,2,1]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#Output:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  3
2  3  2
3  4  1
```

Figuring out which columns contain increasing values is just a question of using [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) on all values in the dataframe, and checking which ones are increasing throughout the whole column.

That can be written as:

```
out = (df.diff().dropna()>0).all()
#Output:
a     True
b    False
dtype: bool
```

Then, you can just use the column names to select only those with `True` in them

```
new_df = df[df.columns[out]]
#Output:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

---

*(the term cumulative doesn't really represent the conditions you used.Did you want it to be cumulative or just increasing? Cumulative implies that the value in a particular row/index was the sum of all previous values upto that index, while increasing is just that, the value in current row/index is greater than previous.)